# Disable but keep dropdown entries

Tags: html, asp.net, vue.js

I have a Vue.js form that is used to add and update data for patients. My concern is a `<select>` tag allowing me to add a *relative* populated by an array `PPrelations`, itself populated by a select statement from a database that includes a table called *Relative*, this table has entries like (1,brother, A), (2, coworker, I) and so on.
The application's `<select>` currently has options like *brother, father, friend, coworker, …*, if I add a new entry now I can select *friend*, I want to **remove** the non family options (like friend and coworker) for future entries yet keeping it for existing one, meaning if old patient John has *friend* used as a relative, it should show, but if a new entry Joe is to be added, I cannot add friend or coworker as relatives.

It was suggested modifying the source table which is now  **Relative(id, desc, status)**. Status can be **I** or **A** for active/inactive, old one did not have a status column.

```
<select id="PPRelOtherConType" v-model="PPRelationOtherCon">
<option v-for="rel in PPrelations" v-bind:value="rel.RELATID">{{rel.RELATDESC}}
</option>                                              
</select>
```

But I am stuck here returning the active entries would give an empty field. Any ideas how to do it?

Comment: The first half of the question makes sense, but then...  "_I want to remove the non family options ... yet keeping it for existing one_", don't know what that means, "_which is now Relative(id, desc, status)_" don't know what that means. "_Status can be I or A for active/inactive._" don't know what that means.  "_returning the active entries would give an empty field_" don't know what that means...  We have 0 knowledge of your app, use cases, or requirements.  If the information in relevant, you have to explain it in a way that someone not familiar with your app _at all_ can understand.

Comment: I hope it is clearer now

Answer (score 1):

I/A (inactive/active) is not a good description of the data "next-of-kin", you should use something more accurate like "IsBloodRelated" (true/false)

```
Database record
Id, Desc, IsBloodRelated

Database table entries
1 father, true
2, mother, true
3, brother, true
4, sister, true
5, grandfather, true
6, grandmother, true
7, uncle, true
8, aunt, true
9, nephew, true 
10, niece, true
11, co-worker, false
12, friend, false
13, legacy-next-of-kin-invalid, false
```

When the form is displayed, and the person's next of kin is NOT blood related (co-worker or friend), then the dropdown element could display "please update next of kin" or "legacy next of kin invalid" or the current next of kin value with "(invalid)" added to the end like "co-worker (invalid)"...

When the form is submitted, you compare the selected option to the database list...

If IsBloodRelated equals True, then the next of kin entry is valid

If IsBloodRelated equals false, then the next of kin field is invalid and a new selection should be made from the dropdown before allowing saving / updating the record...

To disable the dropdown, while keeping the entries, set it's attribute readonly="readonly"

UPDATE
I've pasted the sample page below.
All the .NET code is in the page, not code-behind, a personal preference of mine, but it shouldn't be difficult to figure out which bits you need.

Also I've hard coded the patients list and the next of kin list, rather than making a table but you should use your existing table and populate you next of Kin list as before.

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<script runat="server">
    '
    '-> NextOfKin structure
    Private Structure NextOfKin
        Public Index As Byte
        Public Description As String
        Public IsBloodRelated As Boolean
    End Structure
    '-> NextOfKin List
    Dim pgKinDefns As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of NextOfKin)
    '
    '-> Patients structure
    Private Structure Patient
        Public Index As Byte
        Public Name As String
        Public NxtOfKin As Byte
    End Structure
    '-> Patients List
    Dim pgPatients As System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Patient)
    '
    '-> Page vars
    Dim pgTmpId As Byte

    '-> Page load event
    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        '
        '-> Initialise
        pgKinDefns = New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of NextOfKin)
        pgPatients = New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Patient)
        '
        '-> Build list of kin defintions
        AddKinDefintion(0, "father", True)
        AddKinDefintion(1, "mother", True)
        AddKinDefintion(2, "brother", True)
        AddKinDefintion(3, "sister", True)
        AddKinDefintion(4, "grandfather", True)
        AddKinDefintion(5, "grandmother", True)
        AddKinDefintion(6, "uncle", True)
        AddKinDefintion(7, "aunt", True)
        AddKinDefintion(8, "nephew", True)
        AddKinDefintion(9, "niece", True)
        AddKinDefintion(10, "cousin", True)
        AddKinDefintion(11, "legacy-NoK co-worker", False)
        AddKinDefintion(12, "legacy-NoK friend", False)
        AddKinDefintion(13, "legacy-NoK neighbour", False)
        '
        '-> Build list of patients
        AddPatientDefintion(0, "alpha", 0)
        AddPatientDefintion(1, "bravo", 1)
        AddPatientDefintion(2, "charlie", 2)
        AddPatientDefintion(3, "delta", 3)
        AddPatientDefintion(4, "echo", 4)
        AddPatientDefintion(5, "foxtrot", 5)
        AddPatientDefintion(6, "golf", 6)
        AddPatientDefintion(7, "hotel", 7)
        AddPatientDefintion(8, "india", 8)
        AddPatientDefintion(9, "juliet", 9)
        AddPatientDefintion(10, "kilo", 10)
        AddPatientDefintion(11, "lima", 11)
        AddPatientDefintion(12, "mike", 12)
        AddPatientDefintion(13, "november", 13)
        '
        '-> Get current patient id
        If IsNothing(Session("CurPatient")) Then Session("CurPatient") = 0
        If Not IsNothing(Request("hdnPatientId")) Then Session("CurPatient") = CByte(Request("hdnPatientId"))
        pgTmpId = Session("CurPatient")
        If Request("cmdPrv") = "Previous" Then
            If pgTmpId > 0 Then pgTmpId = pgTmpId - 1
        End If
        If Request("cmdNxt") = "Next" Then
            If pgTmpId < 13 Then pgTmpId = pgTmpId + 1
        End If
        '
    End Sub
    '
    Private Sub AddKinDefintion(ByVal pId As Byte, ByVal pDescription As String, ByVal pIsBloodRelated As Boolean)
        '
        Dim Item As NextOfKin
        With Item
            .Index = pId
            .Description = Trim(pDescription)
            .IsBloodRelated = pIsBloodRelated
        End With
        pgKinDefns.Add(Item)
        '
    End Sub
    '
    Private Sub AddPatientDefintion(ByVal pId As Byte, ByVal pName As String, ByVal pKinId As Byte)
        '
        Dim Item As Patient
        With Item
            .Index = pId
            .Name = Trim(pName)
            .NxtOfKin = pKinId
        End With
        pgPatients.Add(Item)
        '
    End Sub
    '
    Private Function ScriptDropdown(ByVal pSelId As Byte) As String
        '
        Dim myThisId As Byte = 0
        Dim myBuf As String = ""
        '
        For myThisId = 0 To pgKinDefns.Count - 1
            myBuf = myBuf & "<option value=" & Chr(34) & pgKinDefns(myThisId).Index & Chr(34)
            If pgKinDefns(myThisId).Index = pgPatients(pgTmpId).NxtOfKin Then
                myBuf = myBuf & " selected=" & Chr(34) & "selected" & Chr(34)
            End If
            myBuf = myBuf & ">" & pgKinDefns(myThisId).Description & "</option>" & vbCrLf
        Next
        ScriptDropdown = myBuf
        '
    End Function
    '
    Private Function GetComboStatus() As String
        '
        GetComboStatus = ""
        If pgKinDefns(pgPatients(pgTmpId).NxtOfKin).IsBloodRelated Then
            GetComboStatus = "disabled=" & Chr(34) & "disabled" & Chr(34)
        End If

    End Function
    '

</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; width: 60%;">
            <div id="FormFields">
                Id:<br />
                <input type="text" id="txtId" name="txtId" size="10" value="<%=pgPatients(pgTmpId).Index%>" readonly="readonly" /><br /><br />
                Name:<br />
                <input type="text" id="txtName" name="txtName" size="30" value="<%=Trim(pgPatients(pgTmpId).Name)%>" readonly="readonly" /><br /><br />
                Next of Kin:<br />
                <select id="Combo1" name="Combo1" size="1" <%=GetComboStatus()%>>
                    <%=ScriptDropdown(pgTmpId)%>
                </select>
                <br /><br />
                <input type="hidden" id="hdnPatientId" name="hdnPatientId" value="<%=pgTmpId%>" />
            </div>
            <div id="PatientRecord">
                Id:<br />
                <span><%=pgPatients(pgTmpId).Index%></span><br /><br />
                Name:<br />
                <span><%=Trim(pgPatients(pgTmpId).Name)%></span><br /><br />
                Next of Kin:<br />
                <span><%=UCase(pgKinDefns(pgPatients(pgTmpId).NxtOfKin).Description)%></span><br />
                <%If pgKinDefns(pgPatients(pgTmpId).Index).IsBloodRelated = False Then%>
                    <span style="color: red;">This record contains a legacy next of kin, please amend next of kin</span><br />
                <%End If%>
                <br />
            </div>
            <div id="Naviagtion" style="float: right;">
                <input type="submit" id="cmdPrv" name="cmdPrv" value="Previous" />
                <input type="submit" id="cmdNxt" name="cmdNxt" value="Next" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: All right helpful, but how to modify the <select> tag?

Comment: Hi again, I'm sorry I'm not sure how to do that with the severside dropdown control (asp:select) but I can knock up some code tomorrow for a standard html dropdown (select)... I had a look at the asp:select docs and it looks like you can use enabled="false" to disable it, but I've not tried it...